# Splitting website traffic by percentage

Tags: php, mysql, loops, foreach

I need to split up traffic to multiple sources based on an assigned percentage. I figure I need a log table like this:

Table:

```
+--------+------+----------------------+
| Source | hits | allocated percentage |
+--------+------+----------------------+
| path1  |  50  | 50                   |
| path2  |  40  | 40                   |
| path3  |  10  | 10                   |
+--------+------+----------------------+
```

I figure the logic needs to loop through all the paths and calculate the current percentage and then determine which one is furthest from the "allocated percentage" and then update the table `hits=hits+1`. I'm having trouble with the last compare part.

```
$overall_hits = $db->getall('Select sum(total_hits) from table');

$source = $db->getall('Select * from table');
foreach($source as $row){

    $current_percentage = ($row['total_hits']/$overall_hits)*100;

    //how should I compare? what if they are equal?
    if($current_percentage < $row['allocated_percentaged'])
    {      

    $chosen_path = $row['source'];
    $db->sql("Update table set total_hits=total_hits+1 where source='".$chosen_path."'");
    break;    

    }else{

    continue;

    }

}
```

Am I even on the right track here?

Comment: This isn't part of your actual code, is it? `foreach(source as row){` --- call it *pseudo*?

Comment: What you need is a A/B test framework: http://phpabtest.com/

Comment: is that a typo? because the string inside the `fetchAll()` method is missing a single quote

Comment: Why would you need to determine which one is furthest from the "allocated percentage"? A random generator might not be perfect, but in the long run you will get your percentages automatically.

Comment: Ditto to that. Just use a random number generator; that's much easier and probably more accurate than trying to ensure that 40% really means 40%.

Comment: This is not the actual code. I was just trying to explain it a bit. forgive the typos and shorthand. I'm a noob on here. There is a monetary value associated with every path. The higher the percentage the higher the value so I need to allocate the traffic there.

Comment: @JakeGould - There is code in my post and an example of the table. I'm not asking for some one to code it for me, just some advice on how to do the compare logic.

Comment: @user3618776 You're trying to implement some kind of load balancing?

Comment: @Alex.Ritna - not load balancing, I just need to send users to different areas of a site.

Comment: @SuperJetxH2O based on which areas of the site have the lowest hit to allocation ratio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presuming I understand what you're trying to do, you can do all of the logic checks in your SQL.

Using the following data as an example:

```
CREATE TABLE t (
  source TEXT,
  hits INT,
  percentage INT
  );

INSERT INTO t (source, hits, percentage)
VALUES 
  ('path1', 41, 50), 
  ('path2', 27, 40), 
  ('path3', 3, 10)
```

You can simply run a query against the entire table, to calculate what percentage each of the paths is at:

```
SELECT 
  source, 
  hits, 
  percentage, 
  (hits / percentage) * 100
    AS current 
  FROM t
  ORDER BY current ASC;
```

Which will give you the following results

```
SOURCE  HITS    PERCENTAGE  CURRENT
path1   3       10              30
path2   27      40              67.5
path3   41      50              82
```

You can then simply add `LIMIT 1` to the end of your query, to only obtain 1 result. This will give you the path with the lowest number of `hits : allocated` ratio.

```
SOURCE  HITS    PERCENTAGE  CURRENT
path1   3       10              30
```

You can see it in action on SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2195a/4).

Comment: Thanks it did not occur to me to do it with mysql